# Using a dynamic connection string with the Breeze EFContextProvider

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

> At the moment i have an application (web/silverlight) where the connectionstring for my ObjectContext is dynamic. It is based on how a user logs in because each of my customers have their own database. ie.. username@domain. I'm trying to find a way to use the EFContextProvider which would be by either passing the ObjectContext through the constructor, or by overriding the GetConnectionString, which sadly both aren't supported.
>
> Is there a way to accomplish this, or can i download the source for the EFContextProvider somewhere so i can implement it myself ?
>
> Thanks in advance.

This question was posted by Marcel on our IdeaBlade forums. I am reposting the question and answer here since I think it will be useful to the Breeze Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to download the source and modify it for such a simple thing. And **now you won't have to**.

We've pushed to GitHub a simple update to `EFContextProvider`. This change will appear in the next Breeze Runtime version (> 0.81.2).

Where `EFContextProvider` used to create the 'T' (your ObjectContext/DbContext) as follows:

```
_context = new T();
```

It now calls upon a virtual method, `T CreateContext()` instead, whose default implementation is:

```
protected virtual T CreateContext() {
    return new T();
}
```

Override and replace that in your `EFContextProvider` subclass and you will be able to make your context of type 'T' just the way you like it.

**N.B.: The base `EFContextProvider` will still do a little post-creation configuration** to make sure it behaves as we expect; we don't want the context doing any lazy loading or creating proxies.

So if 'T' is an `ObjectContext`, the provider will do this:

```
objCtx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

and if 'T' is a `DbContext` it will do this:

```
dbCtx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
dbCtx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: how could this be used to change DB connection string per call? Example: 2 company DBs with different connections strings but exact same model. Controller gets a param based upon which a correct conn string can be supplied...

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded the source and added a constructor to the
>   EFContextProvider which accepts an instance of T to be able to use an
>   existing ObjectContext/DbContext which works like a charm.

Marcel figured it out by himself and answered his own question on our forum.

Comment: Is this the best solution? I don't want to download source and make changes preventing me from updating to newer versions of Breeze. I do need the context to be based on a connection string name, or even better a dbcontext I create.

Comment: No it is not a good solution. It should be possible to supply your own context factory. I'll put that on the list.

Answer (score 1):

The CreateContext virtual method, mentioned by Ward, is now available in v 0.83.2