# Breeze EFContextProvider per request and based on parameter?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, entity-framework-6

I have a multi-tenant app in which user can select "current company" after they log in.
There is a DB per company but the model is the same, the workflow is the same, and the controller actions are same....The user can switch companies while being logged in and all actions need to be 'directed' to proper DB.

[I know it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13616832) to customize context creation in `EFContextProvider<T>` by overriding `CreateContext()` but how do I pass the extra info (parameter, e.g. CompanyId) that would allow me to create context with correct connection string?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way is to include the tenant id in a custom HTTP header.

Because the tenant id changes during the session, you probably want to create a [custom Breeze ajax adapter](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax) (wrap the one you're using now) that sets this header dynamically during its implementation of the `ajax` method.

On the server you fish the header out of the request.

**MAKE SURE YOU ARE VALIDATING USER AND HEADER ON THE SERVER**

Comment: I will have to instantiate EFContextProvider in each action method of BreezeController instead of once per class then - correct?

Comment: No. An instance of the CLASS is instantiated for each request. I assume you instantiate the `ContextProvider` (or better inject a repository/Unit-of-Work instance) in ctor. I don't remember if you have access to the http request in the ctor. Maybe not. If not, you'll have to pick it out in each method. But since you'll be calling the context provider there and ***it's your context provider*** it will be your logic that picks up the request and fishes out the identifying header anyway.

Comment: You are correct! I can do it in constructor as the class instantiates per request!. I also coupled that with OWIN middleware component that extracts tenant from header...Thanks for the suggestion!