# Using Breeze/EntityFramework/WebAPI with multiple databases

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

We currently have a Silverlight app that uses DevForce 2012.  Like much of the Silverlight world, we've started porting over to HTML5.  We will be using Angular backed by Breeze coupled with EntityFramework/WebAPI.

Each of our customers has its own database, all sharing the same model.  Since we have several hundred customers, our web.config contains several hundred connection strings.  When a user logs in, they enter their account code, which is directly linked to a connection string.  DevForce has a concept of "data source extensions" which is what our Silverlight app uses to get the correct connection.  So an example of our config would be

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Entities_123" connectionString="myConnectionString" />    
   <add name="Entities_456" connectionString="myConnectionString2" />
   ...
</connectionStrings>
```

So a user enters "456" as their account code when they log in, we pass that value as the "data source extension" to DevForce, and that connection is associated to the user for the rest of the session thanks to DevForce magic.

What I have a hard time wrapping my head around is how to do a similar thing with Breeze/EF.  I've scoured the web and cannot find any examples of how to use Breeze to connect to multiple databases without having to create multiple Controller/Context classes.  I'm guessing I will need to use a DBContextFactory in some fashion, but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is as much a security issue as a database selection issue. Therefore, I'd continue your practice of having the server determine the database id based on the authenticated user.

**The client should not know or influence the choice of database id directly.** That's a private matter that belongs on the server.

**Therefore, you don't have to make any changes on the client-side**. From the client perspective, there is a single endpoint and that endpoint is the same for everyone.

### Server (Web API)

You do **not** need a controller-per-database. You may want multiple controllers for other reasons but that's driven by other concerns, not this one.

In your (perhaps *one-and-only*) Web API controller you obtain the database id in some fashion. I don't know how you do it today in Silverlight + DevForce; it's likely the same approach in your Web API controller.

Your controller will instantiate an `EFContextProvider` ... or, better, a repository/unit-of-work component that wraps an `EFContextProvider`, passing along the database id.

You may not be able to obtain the database id in the controller's constructor because the request object isn't available at that time. In this example we'll tell the repository about it inside the controller's `Initialize` method.

Here is the beginning of a Web API controller that may work for you:

```
[BreezeController]
public class YourController : ApiController {
    private readonly YourRepository _repository;

    // default ctor
    public YourController() : this(null) { }

    // Test / Dependency Injection ctor.
    // Todo: inject via an IYourRepository interface rather than "new" the concrete class
    public YourController(YourRepository repository) {
        _repository = repository ?? new YourRepository();
    }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        _repository.SetDatabaseId(getDatabaseId());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the DatabaseId from ???
    /// </summary>
    private string getDatabaseId() {
        try {
            return ...; // your logic here. The 'Request' object is available now
        } catch  {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Of course `YourRepository` delays instantiation of the `EFContextProvider` until someone calls `SetDatabaseId`

Now if you weren't changing connection strings on the fly, you'd be done. But because you are defining the connection string at the last moment, you'll need to create a subclass of `EFContextProvider` and override the `CreateContext` method whose default implementation is:

```
protected virtual T CreateContext() // 'T' is your DbContext type
{
  return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

Clearly you'll have to do something else ... whatever is appropriate for instantiating your `DbContext` connected to the database matching the supplied database id. This is the place for the `DBContextFactory` you mentioned. I'll assume you know how to take care of this.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have these three connection strings in your database of which the first one was created at design time by EF when you created your model. And the remaining two you added yourself and want to use at runtime.

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="TestDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TEST_DB_SERVER\test_dev;initial catalog=Test_1;persist security info=True;user id=dbuser_1;password=pwd1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="TestDbContext_1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TEST_DB_SERVER\test_dev;initial catalog=Test_1;persist security info=True;user id=dbuser_1;password=pwd1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="TestDbContext_2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TEST_DB_SERVER\test_dev;initial catalog=Test_2;persist security info=True;user id=dbuser_2;password=pwd2;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Lets assume you have a Breeze WebAPI controller TestController that internally uses a Repository class TestRepo which implements a ITestRepo interface. If this is not the case then you will have to follow this pattern because it will be required by the Unity Dependency Injection (DI). By the way I am not going to delve into details about how to get the Unity DI package and things of that nature. So assuming that you have the Unity DI installed, below is the full implementation of the UnityResolver class

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

namespace Test.Common.DI
{
    public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        public IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

 public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new UnityResolver(child);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the Unity DI is configured in the WebApiConfig.cs file

```
using Test.Common.DI;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using QuickStaff.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Test
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            string[] connNames = TestController.GetConnectionStringNamesCore();

                if (connNames.Length <= 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ERROR: There needs to be at least one connection string configured in the web.config file with a name starting with 'TestDbContext_'");
                }

                // Web API configuration and services
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.RegisterType<ITestRepo, TestRepo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
                container.RegisterInstance(new TestRepo(connNames[0])); // THIS IS NEEDED IN OERDER TO TRIGGER THE "TestController" CONSTRUCTOR THAT HAS ONE STRING ARGUMENT RATHER THAN THE DEFAULT
                config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);


                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the EF generated model and DBContext class with database-first approach

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace TestModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDbContext()
            : base("name=TestDbContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<EMP_EDUCATION> EMP_EDUCATION { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_POSITIONS> EMP_POSITIONS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_STATUS> EMP_STATUS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_TALENT_TYPES> EMP_TALENT_TYPES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMPLOYEES> EMPLOYEES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LOCATION_TYPES> LOCATION_TYPES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LOCATIONS> LOCATIONS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<POSITION_CATEGORIES> POSITION_CATEGORIES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PosJobClass> PosJobClass { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PRJ_LOCATIONS> PRJ_LOCATIONS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PRJ_POSITIONS> PRJ_POSITIONS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PRJ_STATUS> PRJ_STATUS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PROJECTS> PROJECTS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<REPORTS> REPORTS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now we need to implement a partial class with the same name as above in order to introduce another constructor which will taker in a string parameter containing the connection string that our user will choose on the client-side. So here is that piece of code

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    using Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDbContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a DbContext class with a contructor that takes connection string as its parameter but the problem is how do we invoke this second constructor since we cannot directly invoke it because we are using Breeze’s EFContextProvider which is responsible for invoking the DbContext. The good news is we can override EFContextProvider and here is the code

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    using Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public class EFContextProviderEx<T> : EFContextProvider<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private string _connectionString;

        public EFContextProviderEx(string connectionString){
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        protected override T CreateContext()
        {
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), _connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so far so good. We now need to make use of the above constructor that we introduced. The TestRepo class which implements the ITestRepo interface is where we do this and here is the code for the Respository class along with the interface code for the sake of completion

```
using Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6;
using Test.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Controllers
{

    public interface ITestRepo
    {
        string Metadata();
        SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle);

        IQueryable<POSITION_CATEGORIES> PositionCategories();
    }

    public class TestRepo : ITestRepo
    {
        //public readonly EFContextProvider<TestDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TestDbContext>();
        public readonly EFContextProvider<TestDbContext> _contextProvider;

        public TestRepo(string connectionString)
        {
            _contextProvider = new EFContextProviderEx<TestDbContext>(connectionString);
        }

        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();
        }

        public Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveResult SaveChanges(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }


        public IQueryable<POSITION_CATEGORIES> PositionCategories()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.POSITION_CATEGORIES;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the final piece is our Breeze controller. We need to be able to pass in the connection string info to our Breeze controller somehow. And the way we do this is through a combination of two things. 1) By providing a constructor that takes in an instance of our repository class via the interface, and 2) By Creating an HttpPost API method (SetConnectionString(…)) on our controller to set the desired connection string so that whenever we want to change the connection string we simply call this API and from then on our controller starts working against the appropriate database.

Let us take a look at the code for the controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Breeze.ContextProvider;
using Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6;
using Breeze.WebApi2;
using Test.Models;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Configuration;
using Test.Common.DI;


namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private const string TEST_DB_CNTXT_PREFIX = "testdbcontext_";

        //public readonly EFContextProvider<TestDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TestDbContext>();
        private readonly ITestRepo _repo;

        //public TestController()
        //{
        // UNCOMMENT THIS IN CASE YOU HAVE SOME COMPILE ERROR ASKING FOR THE DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR    
        //}

        public TestController(ITestRepo repository)  
        {
            _repo = repository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string[] GetConnectionStringNames()
        {
            string[] connNames = GetConnectionStringNamesCore();

            SetConnectionStringCore(connNames[0]); // select this as the default on the UI too

            return connNames;
        }
        public static string[] GetConnectionStringNamesCore()
        {
            string[] connNames = new string[0];
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count; i++)
            {
                string cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[i].Name;
                if (cn.ToLower().StartsWith(TEST_DB_CNTXT_PREFIX))
                {
                    temp.Add(cn.Substring(TEST_DB_CNTXT_PREFIX.Length));
                }

            }
            connNames = temp.ToArray();
            return connNames;
        } 

        [HttpPost]
        public void SetConnectionString([FromUri] string connectionString)
        {
            connectionString = SetConnectionStringCore(connectionString);
        }
        private string SetConnectionStringCore(string connectionString)
        {
            connectionString = TEST_DB_CNTXT_PREFIX + connectionString;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                // REGISTER A NEW INSTANCE OF THE REPO CLASS WITH THE NEW CONN. STRING SO THAT ANY SUBSEQUENT CALLS TO OUR CONTROLLER WILL USE THIS INSTANCE AND THUS WE WILL BE TALKING TO THAT DATABASE
                UnityResolver r = (UnityResolver)(this.ControllerContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver);
                r.container.RegisterInstance(new TestRepo(connectionString));
            }
            return connectionString;
        } 

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _repo.Metadata();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _repo.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<POSITION_CATEGORIES> PositionCategories()
        {
            return _repo.PositionCategories().OrderBy(pc => pc.POS_CAT_CODE);
        }

        //// GET api/<controller>
        //public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        //{
        //    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        //}

        //// GET api/<controller>/5
        //public string Get(int id)
        //{
        //    return "value";
        //}

        //// POST api/<controller>
        //public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        //{
        //}

        //// PUT api/<controller>/5
        //public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        //{
        //}

        //// DELETE api/<controller>/5
        //public void Delete(int id)
        //{
        //}
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code the magic happens inside the SetConnectionStringCore(…) which is called by SetConnectionString(…). Basically what we are doing is that with the help of the UnityResolver we are telling the WebAPI framework which instance of TestRepo class to inject into our WebAPI controller.

In case you are wandering about the rest of the code then what is happening is that the client (in my case an Angular SPA) is expected to make an http call to the GetConnectionStringNames() method on our controller to get all the available connection strings and present it to the user so he can choose one. Once he chooses a connection string, the client then calls the SetConnectionString(…) method on the controller to convey that to WebAPI and any calls the client makes thereafter are executed against that database. Also note that I have chosen to present a part of the connection string to the client due to which there is some parsing code. But you could have your own logic for it. A point to bear in mind is that in the WebApiConfig.cs file we are initially using the first connection string encountered.

I hope this helps others because I really had a hard time to get this working. But still I have to thank people who helped me through their posts. Here is the list of pages I consulted.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/c-using-unity-for-dependency-injection-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api/

[Using a dynamic connection string with the Breeze EFContextProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616832/using-a-dynamic-connection-string-with-the-breeze-efcontextprovider)

[Using Breeze/EntityFramework/WebAPI with multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730560/using-breeze-entityframework-webapi-with-multiple-databases/31665501#31665501)

http://cosairus.com/Blog/2015/3/10/programmatic-connection-strings-in-entity-framework-6

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/per-controller-configuration-in-webapi.aspx

As you can see I did not need to override the Initialize method of the WebAPI controller
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)

You may also find this solution at 
https://sskasim.wordpress.com/

**UPDATE:** There is gotcha in the above. It will not work for multi-user scenario since we are changing the connection string for the Web API Controller rather than the instance of the controller. So you will have to use ASP.NET Session and store an instance of the _repo with the appropriate connectionString.

Answer (score 1):

You have a great answer sskasim, and I apologize for not responding to this earlier to explain what I ended up doing.  I ultimately used a DbContextFactory to spin up a connection to the correct database with the client sending the database it wants to connect to with each call.  I also am not using Unity here, although it would be a good improvement.  Here's what I did in case it helps anyone else in the future.

When a user logs in, they provide an account number which corresponds to a connectionString entry in the web.config pointing to which database to use.  The name of the connection strings take the format of "MyEntities_XXX" where XXX is the account number.  So in my entityManagerFactory on the client, I added the following few lines to add the account number to the heading for every call back to the server.

```
    var adapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');
    adapter.defaultSettings = {
        headers: { "account": account.user.accountNumber }
    };
```

Then in the Breeze Controller, I overrode the Initialize method to parse out the account number from the headers and pass it to my repository.

```
[BreezeController]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository = new MyRepository();

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("account", out values))
            _repository.SetAccountNumber(values.FirstOrDefault());
    }

    ...
}
```

When the SetAccountNumber method is called on the repo, it initializes a new MyContextProvider passing the account number into the constructor.  I overrode the CreateContext method from EFContextProvider to use my factory to create the Context.  Those class snippets are below.

```
public class MyRepository
{
    private MyContextProvider _contextProvider = new MyContextProvider("");

    private MyContext Context { get { return _contextProvider.Context; } }


    public void SetAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
    {
        _contextProvider = new MyContextProvider(accountNumber);
    }
}


public class MyContextProvider : EFContextProvider<MyContext>
{
    private readonly MyContextFactory _contextFactory;

    public MyContextProvider(string accountNumber)
    {
        _contextFactory = new MyContextFactory();
        _contextFactory.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    protected override MyContext CreateContext()
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.Create();
        return context;
    }
}


public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public MyContext Create()
    {
        var dbName = "MyEntities" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccountNumber) ? "" : "_" + AccountNumber);
        var contextInfo = new DbContextInfo(typeof(MyContext), new DbConnectionInfo(dbName));
        var context = contextInfo.CreateInstance() as MyContext;

        return context;
    }
}
```

The only "gotcha" here is that there needs to be a generic entry in the web.config for "MyEntities" that EF will use when it generates the metadata.  That's why you see me initially creating a ContextProvider with an empty string as the account number.